# Memory-efficient way to store/compare x amount of trinary (?) values in C#

Tags: c#, performance, processing-efficiency

I have a list of entities, and for the purpose of analysis, an entity can be in one of three states. Of course I wish it was only two states, then I could represent that with a bool.

In most cases there will be a list of entities where the size of the list is usually 100 < n < 500.

I am working on analyzing the effects of the combinations of the entities and the states.

So if I have 1 entity, then I can have 3 combinations. If I have two entities, I can have six combinations, and so on.

Because of the amount of combinations, brute forcing this will be impractical (it needs to run on a single system). My task is to find good-but-not-necessarily-optimal solutions that could work. I don't need to test all possible permutations, I just need to find one that works. That is an implementation detail.

What I do need to do is to register the combinations possible for my current data set - this is basically to avoid duplicating the work of analyzing each combination. Every time a process arrives at a certain configuration of combinations, it needs to check if that combo is already being worked at or if it was resolved in the past.

So if I have x amount of tri-state values, what is an efficient way of storing and comparing this in memory? I realize there will be limitations here. Just trying to be as efficient as possible.

I can't think of a more effective unit of storage then two bits, where one of the four "bit states" is not used. But I don't know how to make this efficient. Do I need to make a choice on optimizing for storage size or performance?

How can something like this be modeled in C# in a way that wastes the least amount of resources and still performs relatively well when a process needs to ask "Has this particular combination of tri-state values already been tested?"?

Edit: As an example, say I have just 3 entities, and the state is represented by a simple integer, 1, 2 or 3. We would then have this list of combinations:

111
112
113
121
122
123
131
132
133
211
212
213
221
222
223
231
232
233
311
312
313
321
322
323
331
332
333

Comment: Packing bits together is going to slow you down a lot-- its only worth it if you need to optimize memory usage over performance.  For example, if you can't fit it in RAM storing these combinations as machine-word aligned structures like int32/int64.

Comment: Bloom filter was designed for this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

Answer (score 0):

Simple mathematic says:

3 entities in 3 states makes 27 combinations.
So you need exactly log(27)/log(2) = ~ 4.75 bits to store that information.

Because a pc only can make use of whole bits, you need to "waste" ~0.25 bits and use 5 bits per combination.

The more data you gather, the better you can pack that information, but in the end, maybe a compression algorithm could help even more.

Again: you only asked for memory efficiency, not performance.

In general you can calculate the bits you need by Math.Ceil(Math.Log( noCombinations , 2 )).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can break this down as follows:

1. You have a set of N entities, each of which can have one of three different states.
2. Given one particular permutation of states for those N entities, you
   want to remember that you have processed that permutation.

It therefore seems that you can treat the N entities as a base-3 number with 3 digits.

When considering one particular set of states for the N entities, you can store that as an array of N bytes where each byte can have the value 0, 1 or 2, corresponding to the three possible states.

That isn't a memory-efficient way of storing the states for one particular permutation, but that's OK because you don't need to store that array. You just need to store a single bit somewhere corresponding to that permutation.

So what you can do is to convert the byte array into a base 10 number that you can use as an index into a `BitArray`. You then use the `BitArray` to remember whether a particular permutation of states has been processed.

To convert a byte array representing a base three number to a decimal number, you can use this code:

```
public static int ToBase10(byte[] entityStates)  // Each state can be 0, 1 or 2.
{
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = 1; i < entityStates.Length; n *= 3, ++i)
        result += n * entityStates[i];

    return result;
}
```

Given that you have `numEntities` different entities, you can then create a `BitArray` like so:

```
int numEntities = 4;
int numPerms = (int)Math.Pow(numEntities, 3);
BitArray states = new BitArray(numPerms);
```

Then `states` can store a bit for each possible permutation of states for all the entities.

Let's suppose that you have 4 entities A, B, C and D, and you have a permutation of states (which will be 0, 1 or 2) as follows: A2 B1 C0 D1. That is, entity A has state 2, B has state 1, C has state 0 and D has state 1.

You would represent that as a boolean array like so:

```
byte[] permutation = { 2, 1, 0, 1 };
```

Then you can convert that to a base 10 number like so:

```
int asBase10 = ToBase10(permutation);
```

Then you can check if that permutation has been processed like so:

```
if (!bits[permAsBase10])
{
    // Not processed, so process it.

    process(permutation);

    bits[permAsBase10] = true; // Remember that we processed it.
}
```

Comment: You're not converting to "base 10". An `int` doesn't hold a "base 10" number, it just holds a number.

Comment: (actually: base2)

Answer (score 0):

Without getting overly fancy with algorithms and data structures and assuming your tri-state values can be represented in strings and doesn't have a easily determined fix maximum amount.  ie.  "111", "112", etc (or even "1:1:1", "1:1:2")  then a simple SortedSet may end up being fairly efficient.

As a bonus, it doesn't care about the number of values in your set.

```
SortedSet<string> alreadyTried = new SortedSet<string>();

if(!HasSetBeenTried("1:1:1"){   
    // do whatever  
}

if(!HasSetBeenTried("500:212:100"){   
    // do whatever  
}

public bool HasSetBeenTried(string set){
    if(alreadyTried.Contains(set)) return false;
    alreadyTried.Add(set);
    return true;
}
```